# Spark SQL Configurations

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

What type of parameters we can set using SPARK SQL? My assumption is Spark accepts the parameters which are prefixed with `spark.sql`, and ignores any other parameters which do not start with `spark.sql` and others can be only be added during Spark session creation.

Let's say, `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`, `spark.sql.broadcastTimeout`, etc. are accepted and `spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem`, `spark.driver.memory`, etc. are ignored. Let me know if my understanding is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark SQL has both static and runtime configurations. One can consult [the online docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-sql) to see whether a particular config has a context, session or a query scope.

> Runtime SQL configurations are per-session, mutable Spark SQL
> configurations. They can be set with initial values by the config file
> and command-line options with --conf/-c prefixed, or by setting
> SparkConf that are used to create SparkSession. Also, they can be set
> and queried by SET commands and rest to their initial values by RESET
> command, or by SparkSession.conf’s setter and getter methods in
> runtime.
> :
> :
> Static SQL configurations are cross-session, immutable Spark SQL
> configurations. They can be set with final values by the config file
> and command-line options with --conf/-c prefixed, or by setting
> SparkConf that are used to create SparkSession. External users can
> query the static sql config values via SparkSession.conf or via set
> command, e.g. SET spark.sql.extensions;, but cannot set/unset them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, How does it work for properties which are not mentioned either in Runtime or Static configuration. Let's Say spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem. Can this be applied at runtime?

Comment: I don't think there is one rule at the moment (I remember seeing some attempt to systemize it though :)), it all depends on where/how Spark uses each setting. For `spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem` specifically, it is used only once, when BlockManager is initialized, so further config changes probably won't affect what actually happens. See https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.2/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/BlockManager.scala#L256